# Proving $\frac{1}{4n}$ converges to $0$ in epsilon-delta form.

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, epsilon-delta

> $$(\forall\varepsilon>0)(\exists K)(\forall x)(x>K\Rightarrow\frac{1}{4x}<\varepsilon)$$

Here is my attempted proof: Let $\varepsilon>0$ be a real number. Let $K$ be $\frac{1}{2\varepsilon}$. Assume $x$ is a real number and $x>K$. Then $x>\frac{1}{2\varepsilon}$, so $x>\frac{1}{4\varepsilon}$. Therefore, $4x\varepsilon>1$, so $\frac{1}{4x}<\varepsilon$.

Is it correct? According to my pen friend who is a math major there's a fault in it but he didn't tell me which, leaving me to figure it out, but I couldn't

**EDIT:** $K$ is a natural number, I think that's the error. So do you have any ideas for a better proof?

Comment: It is correct. Do you need $K$ to be integer?

Comment: $K$ is a natural number, i think that's the error, so how can I prove that?

Comment: well, think about it http://mathworld.wolfram.com/IntegerPart.html

Comment: I don't understand could you expand please

Comment: It's a pretty small fault.  $\lceil x \rceil$ is the smallest integer greater than or equal to $x$, so we can simply let $K = \lceil \frac{1}{2\varepsilon} \rceil$.  (In point of fact, $K = \lceil \frac{1}{4\varepsilon} \rceil$ will work, too, but the previous one leaves your argument otherwise unchanged, except that you must also include that $K \geq \frac{1}{2\varepsilon}$.)

Comment: I think it is a "Archimedean Principle" look at here https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Archimedean_Principle

Comment: I edited the title to reflect what the apparent meaning of the problem is.  If my inference is correct, there is a typo, because you require $|1/4x|$ with an absolute value sign, in all the formulas.

Comment: Also, is $x$ meant to be an integer?  If you expect $K$ to be integer you are doing a convergence proof for the sequence $1/4n$ not the function $1/4x$ with real argument.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following rewrites your proof so that $K$ is a natural number.

Let $\varepsilon>0$ be a real number. Let $K$ be $\lceil \frac{1}{2\varepsilon} \rceil$; note that $K \geq \frac{1}{2\varepsilon}$, therefore. Assume $x$ is a real number and $x>K$. Then $x>\frac{1}{2\varepsilon}$, so $x>\frac{1}{4\varepsilon}$. Therefore, $4x\varepsilon>1$, so $\frac{1}{4x}<\varepsilon$.

Answer (score 1):

In the epsilon arguments, it does not matter if $K$ is integer or not.

"There exists an integer $K$ such that for all $x > K$, fact $F_x$ holds"

is logically equivalent to the same sentence with "integer" replaced by real number.

That is true whether or not $x$ is restricted to integers.

I changed the epsilon formula in the title to something more comprehensible.  If your goal is not to prove that $1/4n$ goes to $0$ the edit is easy to roll back.

Comment: the claim that i had to prove required $K$ to be a natural number

Comment: Right.  I mean that once you prove one thing you have automatically proved the other (in a way that is insensitive to the details of what fact $F_x$ might be).